# Setting a Unity SerializedProperty value correctly

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, ironpython

I'm using IronPython to do (Editor only) cleanup work inside a Unity3d project. This works great except for one irritating gotcha.

I've got a Python wrapper class that hides the C# verbosity of using SerializedProperties:

```
class PropertyProxy(object):
    PROPTYPES = {
        SerializedPropertyType.Integer:"intValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Boolean:"boolValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Float:"floatValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.String:"stringValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Color:"colorValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference:"objectReferenceValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.LayerMask:"objectReferenceValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Enum:"enumValueIndex",
        SerializedPropertyType.Vector2:"vector2Value",
        SerializedPropertyType.Vector3:"vector3Value",
        SerializedPropertyType.Vector4:"vector4DValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Rect:"rectValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.ArraySize:"arraySize",
        SerializedPropertyType.Character:"objectReferenceValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.AnimationCurve:"animationCurveValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Bounds:"boundsValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Gradient:"objectReferenceValue",
        SerializedPropertyType.Generic:"objectReferenceValue"
     }


    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner
        self.prop_path = self.PROPTYPES[owner.propertyType]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.owner.serializedObject.targetObject.name +"." + self.owner.propertyPath


    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.owner.isArray:
            return []
        else:
            return getattr(self.owner, self.prop_path)

    @value.setter
    def set_value(self, val):
        setattr(self.owner, self.prop_path, val)
        self.owner.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()
```

The `get` functionality works fine, and returns correct values. The setter, however, complains. If you try to set the value of a `PropertyProxy` I get an error claiming the I'm trying to set a read-only attribute.  This isn't literally true - I can do this:

```
 myPropertyProxy.owner.floatValue = 2.0
```

with no problem, but when the setter is trying to do

```
 setattr (myPropertyProxy.owner, 'floatValue', 2.0)
```

I get the error.

I assume this is some kind of issue with IronPython being unable to get the right setter for a property on the Unity side, but I'm just guessing. Does anybody have more info on what's really going on here?

**Update**

Issuing

```
setattr(myProp.owner, 'floatValue', 2.0)
myProp.owner.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()
```

directly - that is *outside* the class - works.  Grrr.

**Update 2**
The `value` and `set_value` functions work if you call them without the property decorator :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem turns out to be a quasi-red herring; the code posted above works if you convert

```
@property
def value(self):
    if self.owner.isArray:
        return []
    else:
        return getattr(self.owner, self.prop_path)

@value.setter
def set_value(self, val):
    setattr(self.owner, self.prop_path, val)
    self.owner.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()
```

to the more old-fashioned:

```
def _value(self):
    if self.owner.isArray:
        return []
    else:
        return getattr(self.owner, self.prop_path)

def _set_value(self, val):
    setattr(self.owner, self.prop_path, val)
    self.owner.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()

value = property(fget = _value, fset = _set_value)
```

I think this represents a divergence between CPython and IronPython in their implementation of the @property decorator, since in ordinary CPython the two are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand completely what you are trying to do, anyway speaking about [SerializedProperty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html).

When you want to set the value of a `SerializedProperty` (typically writing custom inspectors code) you have several ways:

- Use a [PropertyField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) to automatically display it with default style
- Access a field through `SerializedProperty`  and deserialize back SerializedObject(like your approach)
- Wrap SerializedProperty access using [EditorGUI.[Begin|End]Property](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.BeginProperty.html)
- Access directly a serialized field.

Now, every approach depends on the specific use case and has eventually its drawbacks. The main thing to keep in mind is that **[de]serialization process in handled by a different thread** that need to know which `SerializedProperty` has been modified before deserialize it back.

So in your case (if I understood it correctly) you need to make at least 2 functions call in order to make it work in every situation:

1. Call [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.Update.html) (or [UpdateIfDirtyOrScript](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.UpdateIfDirtyOrScript.html) depending on the case) before modifying any property. This ensure you are referring to a consistent `SerializedObject` state.
2. Modify the `SerializedProperty` (like you are doing)
3. Call `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties`(like in your update)

> I assume this is some kind of issue with IronPython being unable to
>   get the right setter for a property on the Unity side, but I'm just
>   guessing. Does anybody have more info on what's really going on here?

I don't know much about Python so I don't have a clear answer but probably this is related to the fact that floatValue setter referes and external function (probably in the C++ side of the engine):

```
public extern float floatValue
{
    [WrapperlessIcall]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    get;
    [WrapperlessIcall]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The overarching goal here is to allow myself to script bulk edits to lots of game data (mostly ScriptableObjects) -- things like 'find all the elves with a hitpoint value of 5 and set it to 6'.

I've been working around the immediate issue by converting my property decorators into conventional method calls; I think this must be some kind of IronPython <> cPython delta I haven't seen before.  However the `UpdateIfDirtyOrScript` thing is something I had not seen before, that may explain some issues I've had in other contexts.

Comment: One related question: for assets on disk, would it be possible to just use conventional C# reflection and change the values without the SerializedProperty system at all?

Comment: for assets on disk you can simply edit somehow the files (if stored as text),meta files(for example for prefabs) and eventually the scenes files for prefab overriden properties.. I think it would be tedious because you need to parse yaml by your self and try to keep assets cross references consistents.